# problems with flash in joomla 1.6

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, joomla1.6

I have some problems with showing flash in 1.6,
my sites,

[site1](http://comseguridadltda.com/) and 
[site2](http://sistvc.com/)

they show fine in firefox (and other browsers), but in ie. no luck :(

the first site, shows a purple background instead of transparent for the flash banner,
the second site, doesn't even show the flash

I've installed the   [ie compatibility plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/browsers-a-web-standards/7623) with no luck

the first site I just placed the flash in the code,
in the second site I placed the flash inside an article with a module,

how to fix this please!

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

`<param name="movie" value="/bannerTest.swf" />`

with

`<param name="movie" value="/images/bannerTest.swf" />`